# How does Superman get a clean shave?

Tags: comics, dc, superman

As we all know, Superman is invulnerable, nothing can harm him except kryptonite. We always see Superman in clean shave. So how is it possible, and with what blade does he shave?

Comment: @phantom42 got the ans. Thank you !! :D

Answer (score 2):

He uses his own heat-ray bouncing from mirror to burn the facial hair